# What are the access levels on Salesforce orgs? How to get retrive Managed Package metadata?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am working on a application developed by third party on salesforce , This is a managed package application. I have access to UAT org and some other orgs. When I tried to retrieve the packaged application metadata using salesforce Ant migration tool,I got all the components in the package retrieved successfully. But the content of this components is shown as "(Hidden)". I am not able to see any real code in this components.
Are there any access level restrictions on Managed package? if yes How can I know the restrictions?
Also It will be very great if someone can help with application life cycle management of a managed package application in salesforce. As I am new in this field , Please recommend any tools for the same.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Managed packages are typically used by salesforce.com partners to distribute and sell applications to customers. The code of managed packages cannot be retrieved.